# Turning off Voice-over focus for a cell in table view and not for others

Tags: ios, accessibility

The first cell in my table view is a dummy cell and thus, when Voice-over mode is ON, I want to skip that cell so that the focus does not come to that control 
and thus, none of its traits are spoken by the Voice over. I wrote the code pasted below to acheive the same, thinking that `isAccessibilityElement` alone is sufficient for this. But it seems that is not the case.
Even though this element i said to be non-accessible in the code, still its getting focus by right/left flicks in `Voice-over` mode. Any idea as to how this can be achieved?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
....
     UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
     if(indexPath.row == 0)
     {
          cell.isAccessibilityElement = 0;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use some cutom cell, and within that cell definition implement this:

```
- (NSInteger)accessibilityElementCount {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [(UITableView *)self.superview indexPathForCell: self];
    if(indexPath.row==0){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for a table cell. Now, I want to try the same thing for the UITableViewController, so that the whole controller gets disabled on a particular action and gets enabled on a particular action. I tried using the accessibilityElementCount returning 0 for the custom tableViewcontroller as well but that did not work.

Comment: Shipi, could you accept the answer if this works, so I get credit for it. If you want something more dynamic, what you will want to do is to set a flag in your custom cell, @property BOOL shouldCellBeAccessible;  in accessibilityElementCount you would check that flag instead of checking the indexpath's row. And you would set that flag in cellAtRowForIndexpath... makes sense?

Answer (score 2):

The current way to do this seems to be setting `accessibilityElementsHidden` on the cell to `true`/`YES` (depending on whether using Swift or Obj-C.

Seems cleaner than other answers proposed and seems effective in my very brief testing.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not ideal but could you only display the cell when VoiceOver is not activated? You can use the

```
UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()
```

Function to see if VoiceOver is on when your app loads, and register the

```
@selector(voiceOverStatusChanged)
```

Notification so you can be informed if the user enables or disables voiceover. For more on this see the following blog post.
< http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/05/14/detecting-voiceover-status-changes.html>

Comment: I can do that, but there are other places as well where I need the same functionality of disabling accessibility as well as accessibility focus for other controls. Say for example, I have a left and right pane, like the one we have in email client and I want that the right pane should not get accessibility focus till the time any item on the left pane is selected. Not showing the right pane in such scenario does not seem right. In fact, even the iPad's default email client works in the same manner. So, there has to be some way to disable accessibility focus for particular views or controls.

Comment: Also, please note that I am already using UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning and voiceOverStatusChanged for other purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Just override the cell's function `accessibilityElementCount` like this:

Swift 4.2:

```
override func accessibilityElementCount() -> Int {
   return 0
}
```